# Biztalk 2010 handling exception using the scope in Orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-orchestrations

1. I am trying to handle the errors and put them in the log using Scope. Here is the Orchestration I used,
   [image]
   The Expression_1 has

   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Message Sent to the destination", "Message Sent to the destination");

Expression_2 has

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Failed to send the message to destination", "Failed to send the message to destination --" + exception.ToString() );
```

Expression_3 has

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("General Exception-- Failed to send the message to destination", "Caught GeneralException-- Failed to send the message to destination");
```

When the message is sent without errors it shows up in the log. The message with error doesnot show up I dont know why,
[image]

I don't know what has to be changed.

2. I also don't know how to construct the error message and send it through email without using ESB toolkit. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exception are you trying to catch in your CatchException_1 and CatchException_2?

Comment: Do you have Delivery Notification set to Delivered?

Answer (score 0):

Because your Catch Shape is not configured to catch the exception thrown from scope.

Comment: Try catch Exception in your 2nd catch sharp.

Answer (score 0):

General Exception != System.Exception in BizTalk.
Try to catch System.Exception in second Catch scope.